# Lambda and filter function

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, filter, prime-factoring

I want to know why when I am storing the filtered list into a new list, I am not able to get the desired result

```
def returnsifprimefactors(n):
    """
    This function retruns prime factors of the argument provided
    """
    lst=[]
    for i in range(2,10):
        if n%i==0:
            lst.append(i)
    for j in range(2,10):
        lst=list(filter(lambda n: n==j or n%j, lst))
    print("Prime factors are",lst)
    return
```

If i am changing the  `lst=list(filter(lambda n: n==j or n%j, lst))` into `primelst=list(filter(lambda n: n==j or n%j, lst))`, this function is not working

Comment: both give the same output for me `[2,5]` , also define what is not working clearly

Comment: Since you are using Python3 you may just want to use list comprehension for easier readability... If you give an input and output it would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide the expected and actual outputs.